# How do I search the feed based on tags in the iOS app?

Tags: support, ios-app

Currently I can view only all feeds and cannot filter the feed

Answer (score 1):

You have to add your favorite tags after you logged in. You may add/edit your favorite tags from your home screen right side to filter questions.

You may also add Ignore tags to avoid unrequited questions.

For more information, please visit [what do favorite tags and ignored tags do](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19173/what-do-favorite-tags-and-ignored-tags-do)

Note : This question should be asked on [meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com) as its not compliance with Stackoverflow. Please check [What topics can I ask about here in Stackoverflow?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)